# Starting audio-recording with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediarecorder

I started to make a trial app to do audio recording in Android (with kotlin).

I just followed some tutorial and documentation I found to get started.
But I hit one problem on the way.

Android Studio seems to show some problem by drawing an horizontal line on the word *MediaRecorder*,
as shown in this image, but I do not see any error or other kind of information.

[image]

So my question is: What am I supposed to do?

For reference here is most of the code of the app.

```
package me.soft.myapp

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit private var recordBtn:Button
    lateinit private var stopBtn:Button
    lateinit private var playBtn:Button
    private var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ......
        recordBtn.setOnClickListener {
            println("recordBtn.setOnClickListener")
            if (applicationContext.checkSelfPermission(
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                val permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)
            } else {
                startRecording()
            }
        }
        ......
    }


    private fun startRecording() {
        ......
        stopBtn.isEnabled = true
        playBtn.isEnabled = false
        recordBtn.isEnabled = false

       mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
            ......

            try {
                prepare()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed")
            }

            start()
        }
    }
```

Comment: [This constructor is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#MediaRecorder\(\))

Comment: Use the constructor that takes a Context.  That one is no longer valid and at some point int he future may not work.

Comment: I solved the issue thanks to the 2 comments above.